# Kotlin/Sqlite column not filling

Tags: java, database, sqlite, kotlin

I'm in need of some help troubleshooting a strange behaviour with Kotlin and SQLite database.
When I try filling the database, an entire column gets "skipped".

Here's the database:

```
    "Id" INTEGER,
    "fornitore_pi"  TEXT,
    "fornitore_denom"   TEXT,
    "fornitore_cap" TEXT,
    "fornitore_indirizzo"   TEXT,
    "fornitore_comune"  TEXT,
    "fornitore_provincia"   TEXT,
    "fornitore_nazione" TEXT,
    "cliente_pi"    TEXT,
    "cliente_denom" TEXT,
    "cliente_cap"   TEXT,
    "cliente_indirizzo" TEXT,
    "cliente_comune"    TEXT,
    "cliente_provincia" TEXT,
    "cliente_nazione"   TEXT,
    "data"  TEXT,
    "numero"    TEXT,
    "tipo"  TEXT,
    "divisa"    TEXT,
    "importo"   TEXT,
    "scadenza"  TEXT,
    "mod_pagamento" TEXT,
    "iban"  TEXT,
    "pagamento" TEXT,
    "condizioni"    TEXT,
    "pagata"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
```

And here the Kotlin insertion function I wrote:

```
fun insertObject (connection:Connection,bill: BaseBill) {

    val insertionQuery :String = "insert into BILLS (" +
            "fornitore_pi," +
            "fornitore_denom," +
            "fornitore_cap," +
            "fornitore_indirizzo," +
            "fornitore_comune," +
            "fornitore_provincia," +
            "fornitore_nazione," +
            "cliente_pi," +
            "cliente_denom," +
            "cliente_cap," +
            "cliente_denom," +
            "cliente_indirizzo," +
            "cliente_comune," +
            "cliente_provincia," +
            "cliente_nazione," +
            "data," +
            "numero," +
            "tipo," +
            "divisa," +
            "importo," +
            "scadenza," +
            "mod_pagamento," +
            "iban," +
            "pagamento," +
            "condizioni," +
            "pagata" +
            ") values (" +
            "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?" +
            ")"

    val driver = connection.prepareStatement(insertionQuery)

    var counter = 0

    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["fornitore_pi"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["fornitore_denom"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["fornitore_cap"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["fornitore_indirizzo"]?.normalizer())
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["fornitore_comune"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["fornitore_provincia"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["fornitore_nazione"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["cliente_pi"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["cliente_denom"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["cliente_cap"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["cliente_indirizzo"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["cliente_comune"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["cliente_provincia"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["cliente_nazione"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["data"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["numero"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["tipo"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["divisa"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["importo"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["scadenza"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["mod_pagamento"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["iban"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["pagamento"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["condizioni"])
    driver.setString(++counter,bill.features["pagata"])

    driver.execute()
```

Now the strange fact about this is that it generates no errors at all, but the values that should go under the `cliente_indirizzo` column get all skipped. So the column `cliente_indirizzo` gets filled with `cliente_comune` values and everything is moved one column back, generating all null values on the last column.
What am I missing? Any idea about this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Values mismatch. |You have 26 field items to fill and you are using 26 question marks for your prepared statements, yet, you are only using 25 p-Statements. You also have `cliente_denom` listed twice in the fields list.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed it out, so trivial. Thanks again. Anyway, since I'm new to SQL, if I may ask another question: do you think this is a good approach? I feel like there are too many calls and maybe too many columns?